# How determine if a Vaadin table row clicked in has been selected or deselected?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Following a user clicking in a row in a Vaadin 7 table, how can I tell 
if the row has been selected or deselected - clicking in a selected row deselects the row - (since there is also a column of 
checkboxes which needs to kept in synch)?

When I tried table.getValue() in an ItemClickListener, this returned null if the 
row is selected and the item id if the row is deselected - i.e. the opposite of
what I would have expected?

```
table.addItemClickListener(new ItemClickEvent.ItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void itemClick(ItemClickEvent event) {

    // how tell if row has been selected or deselected?
    Object idx = table.getValue();
  }
});
```

Thank you,
Steve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Table api you can use the getValue() method, which results the selected rows.

Depending if in multiselct mode or not, you can then deduce what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Vaadin Grid](https://vaadin.com/grid) instead of table. It has the `selectionListener` property which will help you achieve what you need.

[Grid API](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.grid.html)

Answer (score 1):

> (since there is also a column of checkboxes which needs to kept in
>   synch)?

Use [`Grid`](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/components.grid.html) ans set `grid.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTI);` you will have one extra column with checkboxes by default.

Now, If you don't want to use `Grid`.

For `Table` you should use `vaadinTable.addValueChangeListener(...)` instead of `ItemClickListener`.

***For Example :***

```
table.addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        //Set checkbox object as an itemId
        CheckBox itemId = (CheckBox)event.getProperty().getValue();
        //Manage Collection to add selected items
        if(table.isSelected(itemId)) {
            table.select(itemId);
            itemId.setValue(true);//Add this item to collection
        } else {
           table.unselect(itemId); //Remove this item to collection
           itemId.setValue(false);
        }
    }
});
```

One another option is,

```
table.addItemClickListener(new ItemClickEvent.ItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void itemClick(ItemClickEvent event) {
      //Manage collection and manually fetch property of table
      Object value = event.getItem().getItemProperty("property").getValue();
  }
});
```